# How to access a variable initialized within an Ajax callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Kindly assist.

I'm trying to access an object variable which was declared outside JQuery DataTable() function. I have provided settings for Ajax object among which a callback function complete to execute when the request is successfully. Since the async: false is deprecated, I have decided to access the variable initialized from the callback function outside using the setTimeout(). Please see my code to clarify my question.

```
var odata = {
 ids: [],
 dates: []
};
var table = $("#schedule");
table.DataTable({
 ajax: {
   url: "/api/MaintenanceSchedule",
   dataSrc: "",
   complete: function (data, status) {
       if (status === "success") {
         //some codes here
       }

       $("span.machineIds").each(function (index) {
           machineIds[index] = $(this).attr("data-machine-id");//here the array output all elements if you check with console.log()
       });

       $("span.lastMaintained").each(function (index) {
           lastMaintained[index] = $(this).attr("data-last-maintained");
        });

       //the odata properties below have assigned values as seen from the debugger window
       odata = {
          ids: machineIds,
          dates: lastMaintained
       };                           
   }

//some other codes ...

//outside DataTable object

var checkMachineState = function (odata, interval) {
  // some codes...
}

 const INTERVAL = 45000;

setTimeout(checkMachineState(odata,INTERVAL),5000);//odata properties are still not initialized as seen from the debugger
```

The debugger shows the below

odata: Object
dates: []
ids: Array(0)
length: 0
**proto**: Array(0)
**proto**: Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `setTimeout` function is running the function `checkMachineState()` immediately instead of waiting 5 seconds.

That's because `setTimeout` is expecting a *function name* (i.e. just `checkMachineState` without the `()`). But what is entered is a *function expression* (a function with closing `()`, which javascript will run when encountered and resolve to a value).

But you need to have the parenthesis in order to pass the parameters `odata` and `INTERVAL`. The solution is to wrap your function within an anonymous *function declaration* (declaring a function normally will not cause it to run), like so:

`setTimeout(() => {checkMachineState(odata,INTERVAL)},5000);`

Run code below to see what I mean:

```js
console.log("start");
setTimeout(console.log("This runs immediately because of the ()"),10000); //even if delay is 10 seconds

setTimeout(() => console.log("This waits 5 seconds before firing"), 5000);
```

I have written the above with ES6 Arrow notation. You can also write it as:

`setTimeout(function() {checkMachineState(odata,INTERVAL)},5000);`